# Oracle concatenate String null values

Tags: oracle, null, insert

I have this procedure:

```
DECLARE
    r_template_row template_version_row%rowtype;
    r_tag_row  tag%rowtype;
    string_insert varchar2(5000);
    v_rownumber number;
BEGIN
    string_insert := 'insert into template_version(id, name, created_by, created, deleted, rew, filename) values (2, ''new_template'', 1, SYSDATE, ''N'', 1, ''new_template.xls'')';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(string_insert);

    for r_template_row in (select * from template_version_row)
    loop
        v_rownumber := ID_Generator.nextval;
        string_insert := 'insert into template_version_row(id, template_version_id, row_number, name, view_type_id, product_id, created_by, created, deleted, rev, sheet_leg_type) values ('||v_rownumber ||', 2, '|| r_template_row.ROW_NUMBER ||', '||r_template_row.NAME ||', '|| r_template_row.VIEW_TYPE_ID ||', '|| r_template_row.PRODUCT_ID ||', 1, Sysdate,''N'', 1, '||r_template_row.SHEET_LEG_TYPE_ID ||')';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(string_insert);
        for r_tag_row in (select * from tag where TEMPLATE_VERSION_ROW_ID = r_template_row.ID)
        loop
            string_insert := 'insert into tag(id, template_version_row_id, name, tag, tag_value_position_id, data_format, tag_type_id, segment, ipt_table_id, column_name, tag_order, separator, parameter_tag, leg_type_id, segment_template_vers_row_id, created_by, created, deleted, rev, is_mandatory, is_value_mandatory, is_returned_by_get_quote) values (ID_Generator.nextval,'|| v_rownumber ||', '||
                   r_tag_row.NAME ||', '
                || r_tag_row.TAG ||', '
                || r_tag_row.DATA_FORMAT ||', '
                || r_tag_row.TAG_TYPE_ID ||','
                || r_tag_row.SEGMENT||', '
                || r_tag_row.IPT_TABLE_ID ||', '
                || r_tag_row.COLUMN_NAME ||', '
                || r_tag_row.TAG_ORDER||', '
                || r_tag_row.SEPARATOR ||', '
                || r_tag_row.PARAMETER_TAG ||', '
                || r_tag_row.LEG_TYPE_ID || ','
                || r_tag_row.LEG_TYPE_ID||', '
                || r_tag_row.SEGMENT_TEMPLATE_VERS_ROW_ID
                || ', 1 , Sysdate, ''N'', 1, '
                || r_tag_row.IS_MANDATORY || ', '
                || r_tag_row.IS_VALUE_MANDATORY||', '
                || r_tag_row.IS_RETURNED_BY_GET_QUOTE||' )';
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(string_insert);
        end loop;
    end loop;
END;
/
```

I need in insert null values, if cursor.value is empty. Do someone know how to solve this issue. In present code if cursor is empty, then empty string are concatenate in result. Thanks for help. PS: I tried colaesce function, and it complains that I use varchar column.

Comment: What do you mean by **"cursor.value is empty"**? Do you mean when `select * from tag where TEMPLATE_VERSION_ROW_ID = r_template_row.ID` returns no row? Or do you mean that single columns like `r_tag_row.DATA_FORMAT` are null and you want the concatenation result to become null then? Or what else?

Comment: I mean single columns are empty, it means it return null value. If column is empty, i need add ,,null" string into insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`. For columns that are not strings, use `TO_CHAR` to convert them to strings explicitly, so `COALESCE` has to deal with strings only.

```
string_insert := 'insert into tag(id, template_version_row_id, name, tag, tag_value_position_id, data_format, tag_type_id, segment, ipt_table_id, column_name, tag_order, separator, parameter_tag, leg_type_id, segment_template_vers_row_id, created_by, created, deleted, rev, is_mandatory, is_value_mandatory, is_returned_by_get_quote) values (ID_Generator.nextval,'|| v_rownumber ||', '||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.name, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.tag, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.data_format, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.tag_type_id, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.segment, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(TO_CHAR(r_tag_row.ipt_table_id), 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.column_name, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(TO_CHAR(r_tag_row.tag_order), 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.separator, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.parameter_tag, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(TO_CHAR(r_tag_row.leg_type_id), 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(TO_CHAR(r_tag_row.segment_template_vers_row_id), 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     '1 , sysdate, ''n'', 1, ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.is_mandatory, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.is_value_mandatory, 'NULL') || ', ' ||
     COALESCE(r_tag_row.is_returned_by_get_quote, 'NULL') || ' )';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the dynamic query and if some of the `cursor.value` is null then it just does not put any value and it goes `,,` or `(,` or `,)` in values clause. You can replace them before executing as follows:

```
string_insert := replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(string_insert ,
                                ',,',
                                ',null,'),
                        '(,',
                        '(null,'),
                    ',)',
                    ',null)');
```

Comment: This is also solution, but i prefer something like isNull || null ||

Comment: That will not be possible in your case as coalesce or decode or case when needs the expression as a reuslt of same type for all the conditions.